# How to correct @import scss file inside other scss using Webpack

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, webpack, sass, sass-loader

I using Webpack to compile my SCSS files, based on simplest way:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/home.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader', 
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader',
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Full content of `src/home.js` file:

```
import 'library_name/src/assets/scss/styles.scss';
```

Fragment of `styles.scss` has code like below:

```
@import '../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
```

So, when I run `webpack` command then I get error message:

*SassError: File to import not found or unreadable: ../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss.

on line 5 of ...\node_modules\library_name\src\assets\scss\styles.scss*

Comment: `@import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';`

Comment: @connexo I can't edit path starts with `../../../`, this is contained in a `library_name`, that is not my own:(

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader#resolving-import-at-rules

So for bootstrap:

`@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";`